# How to remove vshost.exe after testing?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, testdriven.net

In VS2010, I'm using TestDriven.net to execute unit tests.  It seems that each time I run a test, another myappname.vshost.exe loads into memory.  It not uncommon to accumulate well over 20 of these processes.  Is there something I can do to prevent this?

Or, is there a quick way to kill all of these processes?

Answer (score 7):

If you disable "Enable the Visual Studio Host Process" checkbox on the debug page of your project properties, this won't spawn. If you notice that this hampers your work - i.e. you need features of the host process, you can try to write a simple script to kill the process that you run after each debug session.

Comment: I tried that but once I run the test in debug mode, it spawn a vshost and leaves it in memory.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure all of your threads are terminating properly? vshost usually does stay in memory, assuming you will debug again soon, but it shouldn't keep spawning new ones if it can use the old one.

Comment: This is only an issue with TestDriven.NET.  My code is single threaded.

Comment: I get the same problem when I run tests with debugger.

This doesnt happen when the same tests are run using NUnit or NCover.

My guess is that this a problem with TestDriven